# Error on SSH command line installing Magento 2 extensions

Tags: magento2.3

I have this error that makes me impossible to continue using SSH. I am installing **MAGENTO 2.3.2** extensions

> Fatal error: Class Magento\Setup\Mvc\Bootstrap\InitParamListener
>   contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or
>   implement the remaining methods
>   (Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface::__invoke) in
>   /home/vaporartuk/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Mvc/Bootstrap/InitParamListener.php
>   on line 33

Does someone know how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Most people resolved this issue by this command

> `composer self-update` and `composer update`

**Hope it Helps.**

Comment: With composer update -vvv I have an error [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                               
  The "https://getcomposer.org/download/update/composer.phar.sig" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)